# Move constructor call optimization on explicitly created rvalue

Tags: c++

```
class C
{
public:
    C()
    {
        std::cout << "C()" << std::endl;
    }
    C(C &&c)
    {
        std::cout << "C(C &&)" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    C c = C();
}
```

I've assumed this would print
`C()`
`C(C &&)`

since C() creates a temporary object (rvalue),
but this actually prints only
`C()`
in MSVC.
Is this because of some kind of optimization?

Comment: Yes, the compiler removes the temporary object entirely when a temporary object is created just to get copied.

Comment: thanks, you are right. It was also on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) @DimChtz